# Finding the biggest subset of unique dominos

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I have a bunch of dominos and am trying to find the largest subset of them such that no domino in my subset has a face that matches any other face in my subset (each domino has two faces).  These are special dominos where each face can have any positive integer number of dots.  There are also no 'double' dominos with both ends showing the same value.  I also have around 5000 of them, so a brute force search of all possible subsets is prohibitive.

It has been many years since I graduated university, and this problem seems beyond anything that I remember from my C&O classes.  My best idea so far was to create a graph where each vertex coresponds to a face value, and where each domino in my starting set representing an edge between two vertices.  I then created an algorithm where I select edges in passes, removing them from the graph in the process.  Each pass where an edge is removed, I add it to my subset and also remove the vertices at both ends of the edge as well as any other edges that may be leading into those vertices (these extra edges are not added to my selected set).  I decide to select an edge by:

- Any edge where at least one of its vertices has only a single edge
- Otherwise, any edge where removing it will not cause an isolated
  vertex to be created (ie, a vertex that has not been removed but also no longer has any edges connecting to it).

While this algorithm is fast and works reasonably well, it does not seem to work all the time.  I also cannot prove that it is correct for all cases.  Does anyone know the right way to go about solving this?

Comment: You want to find a "Maximum Matching" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Definitions ... A bit further down they discuss algorithms to find MMs ... but the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm is for a bipartite graph.

Comment: This might be nearer to what you are looking for (Not that I begin to understand) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching

Comment: Thanks.  That looks just like what I need.